# How to sort a Perl array on every nth element

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I have a Perl array read from a tab-separated file in the format:

```
FirstName1 TAB LastName1
FirstName2 TAB LastName2
FirstName3 TAB LastName3
```

There are three elements per line -- FirstName, TAB, LastName -- which is necessary because not all last names are single strIngs

For instance

```
Betty Van der Bildt
```

How do I sort the array on LastName then FirstName, preserving the TABs, please?

Comment: Please write in English. IOW doesn't come up immediately if I google, and to me means Isle of Wight. And are you saying that there is a comma each side of the tab?

Comment: @Borodin "In other words"...

Comment: I can't tell what the three lines you posted are supposed to represent. Is that the actual file contents? Is that your idea of what the array looks like? Also, what have you tried so far, and in what way is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Ah! Thanks. I was wondering about “I only want”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you mean is this

```
my @sorted_names = sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map [ split /\t/ ], $a, $b;
    $aa->[1] cmp $bb->[1] or $aa->[0] cmp $bb->[0];
} @names;
```

---

Here's the data directly from your comment applied to my sort above. As you can see, the output is sorted by last name followed by first name

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @names = (
    "Mike\tEddelman\n",
    "Saleena\tFAhmad\n",
    "Patrick\tGainley\n",
    "Tim\tHaitkin\n",
    "Sue\tHaitken\n",
    "Desmond\tLeacock\n",
);

my @sorted_names = sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map [ split /\t/ ], $a, $b;
    $aa->[1] cmp $bb->[1] or $aa->[0] cmp $bb->[0];
} @names;

print @sorted_names;
```

#### output

```
Mike    Eddelman
Saleena FAhmad
Patrick Gainley
Sue Haitken
Tim Haitkin
Desmond Leacock
```

---

To do a case-independent sort you should use `fc` on each value to be compared

***Note*** the

```
use feature 'fc'
```

at the top of the program which is essential for this to work. This is available only on version 16 and later of Perl 5

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.16;
use feature 'fc';

my @names = (
    "Mike\tEddelman\n",
    "Saleena\tFAhmad\n",
    "Patrick\tGainley\n",
    "Tim\tHaitkin\n",
    "Sue\tHaitken\n",
    "Desmond\tLeacock\n",
    "Oliver\taabeginningWilliams\n",
    "Christina\tvan Melzen\n",
    "Ekatarina\tvan den Rekk\n",
);

my @sorted_names = sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map [ split /\t/ ], $a, $b;
    fc $aa->[1] cmp fc $bb->[1] or fc $aa->[0] cmp fc $bb->[0];
} @names;

print @sorted_names;
```

#### output

```
Oliver  aabeginningWilliams
Mike    Eddelman
Saleena FAhmad
Patrick Gainley
Sue Haitken
Tim Haitkin
Desmond Leacock
Ekatarina   van den Rekk
Christina   van Melzen
```

Comment: Better; thanks! Could it be because I changed it to declare `$aa, $bb` **outside** the `sort`? Still have the following names out of order, though: `Oliver aabeginningWilliams
Christina van Melzen
Ekatarina van den Rekk` as there are two whitespaces in the `van *`?

Comment: @marksealey: *"Could it be because I changed it to declare `$aa, $bb` **outside** the sort?"* Probably not, unless you have the whole assignment line outside the block. But don't do that. It's sounds like you are one of the people who has all of your variables declared in a huge block at the top of the program, in twenty-year-old C-style. That defeats the advantages of `use strict`, and everything should be declared as *late* as possible, usually where it is first assigned.

Comment: @marksealey: *"I still have the following names out of order, though*". So does your data for those look like this 
`("Oliver\taabeginningWilliams\n", "Christina\tvan Melzen\n", "Ekatarina\tvan den Rekk\n")`? That would be because lower-case letters are sorted *after* upper-case ones. To sort names independently of case you should use the `fc` feature of Perl to "fold" the case. I'll amend my answer again

Comment: thanks so much! All working now :-)  Yes, I typically do declare everything in carefully commented blocks at the top - because I learnt Perl almost 20 years ago too and don't use it often enough to refine it this way! But now, having followed the suggestions you have so kindly and patiently offered, it's all working just as it should. I've learnt a lot. Again, much appreciated!

Comment: @marksealey: *"I typically do declare everything in carefully commented blocks at the top"* Perl doesn't read the comments! I trust that you `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`, but that won't protect you from accidentally reusing the same variable name and getting obscure bugs as a result. The scope of all variables should be as small as possible

Comment: thanks again! I know about the comments :-) said that as a mark of meticulousness. I appreciate your advice. Clearly need to do some relearning! Comments about scope noted.

Answer (score 1):

Borodin's answer is fine if you only have a small group of things to sort.  You can use a Schwartzian transform to make things more efficient though.

```
my @sorted_names = 
    map $_->[1],                    # Extract original values
    sort { 
      $a->[0][1] cmp $b->[0][1]  # Two level sort
      || $a->[0][0] cmp $b->[0][0]
    }  
    map [ [split /\t/], $_ ],       # Precompute comparison function, saving original values
    @names;
```

Caution - I haven't benchmarked this.  For some data sets repeatedly splitting the strings may be faster than accessing the deep array structure.  In general, if you have expensive sort criteria and a big data set, this technique is a winner.

Comment: In general you shouldn't start to optimise your code until it is complete and tested and you have found it to be too slow. In that situation you should profile your code to find the bottlenecks and optimise those rather than just improving things at random.

Comment: @Borodin, agreed.  Also, one, er me, shouldn't make blanket statements about speed without benchmarks.  I got it half right.  However, The Schwartz is a pretty standard perl idiom, and it is worth documenting.

Comment: Borodin, daotoad,

Thanks very much for your help. But I can't get either to work as I want.

My fault for not articulating correctly how I think the array is constructed - as Matt asks.

So far I'm reading in a text file with 3 components on each line: FirstName TAB LastNames. I'm pushing the FirstName TAB LastNames onto @names.

Borodin's completes but doesn't sort as expected - producing:

FirstName1
FirstName2
FirstName3
LastName1
LastName2
LastName3

It doesn't preserve the TABs

daotoad's results in: 'Can't use string ("0") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at line 130'

Comment: @marksealey: My code doesn't modify the contents of `@namesd` at all, it just reorders them, so everything is "perserved". I assumed that by `TAB` you meant the horizontal tab character, which isn't a separate field. If not then I can't imagine what you might mean. Do you have the literal characters `TAB` in your file? Add `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; print Dumper \@names;` to your code and put the result in your question so that we can see what you're really dealing with

Comment: @borodin, Thanks. I've made progress. Got your code to half-work by recoding the way I build the array(s). So maybe best to ask you to advise on that first, please: it now sorts - but only on FIRST name! Array formed (per 'Dumper') thus:
`"Mike\tEddelman\n",
  "Saleena\tFAhmad\n",
  "Patrick\tGainley\n",
  "Tim\tHaitkin\n",
  "Sue\tHaitken\n",
  "Desmond\tLeacock\n",`

Comment: @marksealey: Well I have no idea what you're doing but that just isn't true. Please see my solution, which I have updated to show my code applied to the data you have posted in your comment. The result is exactly what you asked for. I notice you still have the newlines at the end of each name, which you should remove with `chomp @names`, ore preferably by using `chomp` on each line as you read it from the file

Comment: @daotoad: I've just discovered that your solution is also wrong. The sort expression needs to be in a *block*